# Passing Jenkins environmental variables to plugins edit box fields?

Tags: jenkins

I have some jobs set up with TFS plugin and it takes project path parameter. Is there a way to set that as *Jenkins > Configuration > Environment* variable. In this way I could easily switch between trunk and branch codes without changing values for each job.

I have tried `${project_path}` in the plugin but it doesnt work. Like how the workspace name can be changed by using jenkins environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is no way to do it and its the way its developed hmmm.